# Why has this question been bumped by the community 6 times?

Tags: support, bug

Why has [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45568/spatial-dimensions-for-an-animal) question been [bumped by the community](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/45568/revisions) six times?

To me this makes no sense, why would an "ordinary" question be bumped so many times, and therefore appear in the `active`section repeatedly?

Comment: This is an answer which goes deeper and should be asked in meta.stackexchange.com. This community bot is a mechanism of the whole stackexchange community. If you want to ask there, please make sure to search for a possible answer first.

Comment: Do you mind posting it here, once you find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was bumped since [it was an upvoted question that lacked an upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511) before Oct 22. See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) post in Meta-SE on reasons for bumping questions.